# Detecting force without displacement

Tags: forces

I once made a hand strength test, with something that looked like a regular hand trainer, but according the nurse was "mute" (in my language), and then further explained that "it won't move when you try to compress it".

It felt like trying to push together a piece of solid metal.

My guess is that it was just a very stiff spring, and "mute" just meant "mute for all practical purposes".

Or is there a way of detecting a force without any actual displacement whatsoever?

Comment: You could have a known force acting on an object.  When you then add the force you want to measure if see no acceleration (and no displacement) you know it's equal to the known force.  This obviously *doesn't* apply your hand strength test but it does answer your final question.

Comment: Consider the many possible designs for [load cells](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_cell).  If there was an electronic readout, it was a load cell.